# Why android mediaPlayer "onBufferingUpdate" is not work well

Tags: android, media-player

```
 mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    hideBgAndLoadProcess();
    if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
      mPlayer.stop();
    }
    Log.e("TAG", "onPrepared is called");
    mPlayer.start();
  }
});
mPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
  @Override
  public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
    Log.e("TAG", "percent is :" + percent);
    sbProgress.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
    int currentProgress =
        sbProgress.getMax() * mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / mPlayer.getDuration();
    Log.e(currentProgress + "% play", percent + "% buffer");
  }
});
```

myPlayer set the "onBufferingUpdateListener" but it not work well,anybody knows why? when myPlayer is playing ,the "onBufferingUpdate" seems never called because the Log is not print.

Comment: What are You trying to play?

Comment: play m3u8 live streaming. this issue is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the listener before starting the media.

Comment: It is not work by add listener before starting the media..but thanks all the same.The bug still there and can not find way to solve it .

Comment: i try this lib's mediaPlayer to instead of the android's,May be it can help you.[lib on github](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle)