# Seekbar not showing buffering secondary bar and when clicked on seekbar the videoview not skipping to the clicked position

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media-player, android-videoview, android-seekbar

I have implemented [this](https://github.com/moyokoo/YoutubeVideoSample) project from github into my project.

I am facing the following problems:

1. The Buffering Seekbar is not showing when the video is playing inspite of the following code in my `onBufferingUpdate` method

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBufferingUpdate(int progress) {
     if (progress != 0){
   bottom_seek_progress.setSecondaryProgress(progress);
        }
   }
   ```
2. The `onStopTrackingTouch` method does not skip video to the new seek bar position, though the `TextView` `time`  gets updated. Below is the method

   ```
   @Override
   public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
   Log.i(TAG, "bottomProgress onStopTrackingTouch [" + this.hashCode() + "] ");
   MediaPlayerManager.instance().startProgressTimer();
   ViewParent vpup = getParent();
   while (vpup != null) {
       vpup.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
       vpup = vpup.getParent();
   }
   if (MediaPlayerManager.instance().getPlayerState() != MediaPlayerManager.PlayerState.PLAYING &&
           MediaPlayerManager.instance().getPlayerState() != MediaPlayerManager.PlayerState.PAUSED)
       return;
   long time = (long) (seekBar.getProgress() * 1.00 / 100 * MediaPlayerManager.instance().getDuration());
   MediaPlayerManager.instance().seekTo(time);
   Log.i(TAG, "seekTo " + time + " [" + this.hashCode() + "] ");
   }
   ```

PS: My `onProgressUpdate` method is as below

```
 @Override
public void onProgressUpdate(final int progress, final long position, final long duration) {
    post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            bottom_seek_progress.setProgress(progress);
            current.setText(Utils.stringForTime(position));
            total.setText(Utils.stringForTime(duration));
        }
    });
    }
```

and my `OnProgressChanged` method is as follows :

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    if (fromUser) {
        long duration = MediaPlayerManager.instance().getDuration();
        current.setText(Utils.stringForTime(progress / 100 * duration));
       }
    }
```

In short my issue is i dont see a secondary buffering bar on top of my primary seekbar and when the video is skipped it doesnt continue from the new seekbar position.

Hope i have made my issues clear..

I also tried the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21828713/buffered-level-of-music-showing-in-seekbar) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17102011/why-android-mediaplayer-onbufferingupdate-is-not-work-well) SO Questions but to no avail..

Please throw light where am i going wrong??

Comment: just wanted to confirm, are you seeting seekbar.setMax(mediaplayer.getDuration)? and are you calculating the progress something like this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40258145/android-mediaplayer-how-do-i-show-a-progress-dialog-while-buffering-audio

Comment: @dastan i am using artplayer library in my project which uses MediaPlayerManager.instance().getDuration .. it has only one variable declared in its onBufferingUpdate method (int progress) i.e `public void onBufferingUpdate(int progress){ }`

Comment: [MediaPlayerManager](https://github.com/maiwenchang/ArtPlayer/blob/master/artplayer-java/src/main/java/org/salient/artplayer/MediaPlayerManager.java) class of the [artplayer project](https://github.com/maiwenchang/ArtPlayer) does not have `MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener()` to implement .. so how to set `seekbar.setMax(mediaplayer.getDuration)` ?? @dastan

Comment: you have to give some max value to seekbar, you can set ```getDuration``` its a public method in that ```MediaPlayerManager```, then only you can calculate progress,  and if its not implemented ```OnBufferingUpdateListener``` then may be you can fork and implement by your self.

Comment: I see its support ExoPlayer then you can take advantage of Exoplayer, Exoplayer is better than Mediaplayer . if you like

Comment: they have ```MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener``` check this file https://github.com/maiwenchang/ArtPlayer/blob/a25072908e4037ba42b919e4ec44d0374df8f82b/artplayer-java/src/main/java/org/salient/artplayer/SystemMediaPlayer.java#L20  and ExoPlayer https://github.com/maiwenchang/ArtPlayer/blob/3a577c1ebafbd9ac03082d2c98de564265abd45b/artplayer-exo/src/main/java/org/salient/artplayer/exo/ExoPlayer.java

Comment: Oh.. thats great.. I'll try it and update you.. thanks a ton.. @dastan

Comment: in my [YouTubeControlPanel Class](https://github.com/moyokoo/YoutubeVideoSample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/m/youtu/YoutubeControlPanel.java)  i got the `onBufferingUpdate` method on line 274.. and  if I add the line `bottom_seek_progress.setMax (int)(MediaPlayerManager.instance().getDuration()` in my `init()` method of my class, the seekBar doesnt move while the video is playing.. and i cant even drag the seekBar..

Comment: you have to calculate progress, the value you are getting in ```onBufferingUpdate``` is 0 to 100 %age value (if I am correct,you can log in logcat), you are setting duration in Time(millis) long value ```setMax()```, you have to convert %age into duration(in millis) , I gave you link earlier, you can check that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40258145/android-mediaplayer-how-do-i-show-a-progress-dialog-while-buffering-audio

Comment: @dastan the problem was (its still is..) in my server.. i updated a video on github and put that link on my code .. the buffering bar on the video now shows correctly... thanks a lot for your valuable inputs to solve my problem...